# Chrome Developer tools throwing an error whenever some javascript error is logged on it from Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, electron, google-chrome-devtools

I have wrapped my create-react-app application in an electron instance. Now whenever I start the electron instance using `electron .`, the web app fires up and works properly but when I open up the dev tools in that window, I cannot see any error logs logged by the javascript in that webapp in the console of dev-tools. The strange thing here is that whenever something is supposed to be logged in the chrome devtools, I see another strange error showing up in the electron logs on the terminal in which I have started this electron instance which is as follows:

`[77673:1004/120603.745812:ERROR:CONSOLE(5509)] "SyntaxError: Unexpected token x in JSON at position 7176533", source: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js (5509)`

This terminal log shows up every time when javascript in the webapp is supposed to log something on chrome devtools. So something is definitely wrong in dev tools due to which the actual error from javascript is not getting logged in the chrome devtools and devtools is throwing the above error on electron terminal.

The create-react-app web app works perfectly fine if hosted normally on a webserver and the devtools log everything properly in that case. 
This issue is specifically related to electron + devtools integration.

Comment: Hi @Anvay, did you find any solution for this issue?